# Missing emails after cancelling my e-mail account

Tags: email, passwords, outlook-express

I stopped being member in a club because the password of the mail account was changed. I was planning to keep the e-mails I had in my outlook express for reference. Only since the password is changed suddenly items I could see offline before are no longer available. It shows a half envelope icon. What could be the cause?

I did compact the e-mails around the same time, but the problem only occurs with the closed account.

I hope anyone can help because it is very inconvenient.
Is the solution to gain access again to the mail account and synchronize once more?

Comment: What's your version of OE?

Answer (score 1):

It probably has something to do with the compacting, since before that you had offline access. It could be that the compacting involved keeping only the headers and not the messages, then you do need to synchronize again…

Comment: Check http://forums.cnet.com/7723-6121_102-536564/outlook-express-has-not-yet-downloaded-this-message/